# nginx doesn't cache json, but caches .jpg file

Tags: json, caching, nginx, fastcgi

My nginx server if configured like this:

```
......
server {
    # Status page
    location /nginx_originserver {
      stub_status on;
    }

    listen 80;

 location ~ ^/1 {
      proxy_pass http://10.10.52.126:1239;
      proxy_cache api_cache;
    }
......
}
```

In this case, when I browse `http://localhost/1/thumbnail.jpg`, the image file is cached. But when I change the proxy to a location which returns `json` like below and browse `http://localhost/1/api_service`, the json file is not cached, why just the image file is cached but not json, how to cache the json file?

```
location ~ ^/1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.10.52.126:8090;
  proxy_cache api_cache;
}
```

Comment: this link https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching/ hope to help

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan that's what I followed, still can't figure out why it just cache image files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;`:

```
location ~ ^/1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.10.52.126:8090;
  proxy_cache api_cache;
  proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
}
```

[Link](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,239063,239077#msg-239077)